# Memory Address Read/Write VB Process

Tags: vb.net, process, memory-address

When i am Running this Block of code it runs, however when i try to change the running process memory address's string value to somethinhg else it give me an error:

```
"System.IndexoutofRangeException Index was outside the Bounds of the Array"
```

These are the Functions:

```
 <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function WriteProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As  IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), ByVal nSize As System.UInt32, <Out()> ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Int32) As Boolean
End Function
Public Shared Function StrToByteArray(ByVal str As String) As Byte()
    Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
    Return encoding.GetBytes(str)
End Function
Public Shared Function Poke(ByVal proc As Process, ByVal target As Integer, ByVal data As Byte()) As Boolean
    Return WriteProcessMemory(proc.Handle, New IntPtr(target), data, data.Length, 0)
End Function
```

This is the button which executes the changed memory address value string.

```
Private Sub saveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveButton.Click
    Try
        Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName.Text)
        Dim Written As Boolean = False

        Written = Poke(p(0), &HB8FDCC, StrToByteArray(TxtVal.Text))

        If Written = True Then

            MsgBox("WriteProcessMemory Sucess!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Poke Memory Status")


        ElseIf Written = False Then

            MsgBox("WriteProcessMemory Failed!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Poke Memory Status")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How many processes are in your `p` array?  I'll be its zero.

Comment: There is only one process that im trying to edit its memory address.

Comment: Well, what do you expect to happen when you mis-type the name of the process

Comment: where is the mis-type of the name of the process above?

Comment: @FBEvo1 - `Process.GetProcessByName()` can return an empty array.  If you break in the debugger is `p` and empty array?

Comment: how would i convert the string array into a byte array, and use it for edit the memory without getting an error?

Comment: @Hans Passant I dont See any mis-spelling of the name of the process, can you explain you findings?

Comment: I don't either, I can't see what you typed into the AppName textbox.  But that's not the point, what do you hope to happen if you typed something random.  Or nothing?  Kaboom is the guaranteed outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the extension of program/application in the name of Process,
in your case, for Chrome
AppName.Text must be "Chrome" instead of "Chrome.exe",
Good Luck.